# ubuntu14 on macbook air but webcam not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam, macbook-air

I installed ubuntu14 on mac book air. Everything works fine except web cam. I installed cheese and it displays "Device not found". I tried various methods like [How to fix webcam on Macbook Pro 5,5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100527/how-to-fix-webcam-on-macbook-pro-5-5) but in its 6th step I dont get any id number as output.Please can anybody can provide me solution for this, since i need to work on simplecv.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you can *only do this on specific Macbooks*, **and**, *they must be Macbook Pros*.

1. [Are you sure you have a Macbook Pro 5,5?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro)
2. Instead of using a binary on Dropbox, have you tried using `apt` to install this?
3. Have you seen if the version you're using is outdated and [has available updates](https://launchpad.net/isight-firmware-tools/)?

Comment: I have macbook air early 2015 and I have already tried apt but no results